# How to choose list_filter by user in admin.py?

Tags: django-admin

I would like a different list_filter to show in admin.py according to the current user. I've tried a few ways to get `request.user` but I can't figure it out. My admin.py is here:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('nickname', 'student_first',)
    list_display = ('nickname',)

    # I need some function to get the current user
    #if request.user.is_superuser:   didn't work
    if get_user:
        list_filter = ('classroom__teacher',)
    else:
        list_filter = (ClassListFilter,)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            stfilter = qs.all()
        else:
            stfilter = qs.filter(classroom__teacher=request.user)
        return stfilter
```

Comment: I think my problem was that I was using `get_user` but it is a reserved name/function.  I changed the name and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was that I was using get_user but it is a reserved name/function. I changed the name and it seems to work

```
def get_loggedUser(self,request):
    logged_in = request.user
    if logged_in.is_superuser:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```